# How to set up touch and click events

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I have a bunch of buttons with onclick handlers, which I want to behave differently when touched. From reading up on the topic, I have come up with this code:

```
var reds = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
for (var idx in reds) {
    var element = reds[idx];
    element.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
        element.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
            alert('stuff');
            event.preventDefault(); // we don't want the 'click' handler
        });
        element.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
            element.removeEventListener('touchend');
            element.removeEventListener('touchmove');
        });
    });
}
```

The theory behind it being that when the user touches the button, I want to wait for him to also let go, if he instead moves(scrolls) the page, I want to ignore that action completely since it obviously was not meant as a 'click'. However, neither the touchend nor the touchmove events get fired, only the touchstart event. So is this setup unviable? What alternative could I use?

Comment: You're ignoring the action when the touch ends, from what you're saying , you want to ignore it if the user scrolls.  Try moving your `touchend` listener into the `touchmove`.

Comment: when touchmove is called, the browser automatically handles the event as a scroll and therefore doesn't invoke the 'click' action - no need to prevent that default (which would disable scrolling if you started on that button) I create them so I can remove them if it turns out it was not the users intention to click.